# Clustering large set of images

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, algorithms, large-data, artificial-intelligence

I've got some big datasets of images (a few million each), and I would like to cluster them **according to images' visual similarities**. I've extracted a feature vector for each image; the space of feature representations is the one I would like to cluster in practice. However, I've had some difficulties because of the following constraints:

- there's no way I can know the number of clusters in advance;
- the clustering algorithm must be stable (it must not be order-dependent);
- I don't want to be affected by the chaining effect (i.e. elongated clusters, where very different images could be linked through a series of small transformation - morphing);
- I would like the solution to be scalable (e.g. by using Apache Spark) or, even better, incremental (online) and efficient. I guess that this last point could be addressed by a streaming clustering algorithm

Given all of these constraints, I am struggling to tackle the problem. All ready-to-go algorithms in Spark MLlib require the number of clusters beforehand. Single Linkage or DBSCAN algorithms are subjected to the chaining effect (see "density reachability" definition in density-based algorithms).

If I had an approximated scalable solution, I think I would be satisfied. I can give up on some of the above constraints if the solution is efficient. To me, it seems that scalable clustering is a hot research topic (I haven't found off-the-shelf solutions).

Of course, I'm not asking for the perfect answer, but I would like to receive some suggestions if some of you have encountered similar challenges before. I've tried some hierarchical clustering techniques, other than Single Linkage (e.g. **Ward's method**), but the time/space complexity (**O(N^2)**) required is too expensive for my datasets; furthermore, it isn't intuitive how to parallelize them.

**Local Sensitive Hashing** seems to hold some interesting properties, however, it seems more suitable for kNN search rather than clustering.

I read this paper: [A Scalable Hierarchical Clustering Algorithm Using Spark](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271217897_A_Scalable_Hierarchical_Clustering_Algorithm_Using_Spark) but, unfortunately, it uses Single Linkage, thus, falling into the chaining effect, which I want to avoid.

Also, this article: [Detecting image similarity using Spark, LSH, and TensorFlow](https://medium.com/pinterest-engineering/detecting-image-similarity-using-spark-lsh-and-tensorflow-618636afc939) seems to be pretty interesting but it doesn't give much insight into the practical clustering details.

Comment: What about using large pretrained image models to classify your images into n categories? Are the images perhaps similar to pretrained models?

Comment: Please, make a search this site first, combining both tags clustering and large-data